# License for programming tutorial on website

Tags: licensing, license-recommendation

I'm wondering what license I should use for a programming tutorial on a website. It will have a mixture of text, media and code snippets.

Ideally, I want to allow others to copy/modify my tutorial only if they give attribution.

Would Creative Commons or MIT be suitable for my purpose?

Comment: What rights do you want others to have with respect to your material?  Is there *anything* you don't want them to be able to do with it, provided attribution is given?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your required protection. If you really want to put an actual code license on the examples, you can of cause use the MIT license for that, although MIT does not require attribution as you require.

But a tutorial is normally not primarily code, but rather a sum of images, text, code and maybe some personal experience and creativity. In my opinion the CC-BY-4.0 might be better suited for this application. Code examples should be sufficiently covered by it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use separate permissive license for code snippets.

This allows to copy & incorporate your code into others.

I wouldn't put attributon requerment for the code, it adds only headache of mentoning your name, usually tutorials are trivial to bother.

On other hand text and other creative material might require attributon, etc.